# Makefiles in openwrt, the difference between cp and $(CP)?

Tags: makefile, embedded, openwrt

I am following a tutorial for compiling my own package in openwrt.

In the /package/helloworld directory:

```
.../packege/helloworld$ ls
src Makefile
.../packege/helloworld$ ls src
hello.c main.c Makefile
.../packege/helloworld$vi Makefile

#helloworld makefile
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

PKG_NAME:=helloworld
PKG_RELEASE:=1
PKG_VERSION:=0.1

PKG_BUILD_DEPENDS:=

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define Package/helloworld
  SECTION:=utils
  CATEGORY:=Utilities
  DEPENDS:=@TARGET_etrax
  TITLE:=Yet Another Helloworld Application
endef

define Package/helloworld/description
 This is helloworld :p
endef

define Build/Prepare
mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
$(CP) ./src/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/
endef

define Build/Compile
$(MAKE) -C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR) \
    $(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS) \
    CFLAGS="$(TARGET_CFLAGS)"
endef

define Package/helloworld/install
$(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/bin
$(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/helloworld $(1)/usr/bin/
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,helloworld))
```

I have two questions about this Makefile:

1. I found there are commands, such as mkdir, $(CP),$(MAKE). I changed $(CP) to cp, and the compiling goes well. So I don't understand why these two kinds of formats exsits.
2. Where the parameters, such as $(PKG_BUILD_DIR), $(INSTALL_DIR), are defined in openwrt? I just found the place where $(TOPDIR) is defined but not the others.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. These are not different kinds of formats, **cp** is a [Linux command](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_cp.htm), $(CP) is a makefile construction for "getting the value of make variable **CP**". Thus, under Linux it should expand to **cp** (i.e. should be  initialized with this value somewhere), and , most probably, to **copy** under Windows (this is all particular setup-dependent since **cp** is not fully the same as **copy**). The same with $(MKDIR) and other system tools.

   1.1. $(MAKE) is actually another thing - this is a special make variable which expands to make tool name with arguments/flags passed from command line. Read [this](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/MAKE-Variable.html#MAKE-Variable).
2. These are all variables controlling where to build and where to install. See description [here](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/packages).